# Changing Variable Value on Click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, onclick

I am using the dribbble API to GET my works from dribbble.

I set up a few VAR's to help with the process;

```
var dribbble = 'crobertson97';          
var limit = '10'; //items per page
var per_page = '&per_page='+limit+''; //url 
var accessToken = '12345678910'; //client
var url = 'https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/'+dribbble+'/shots/?access_token='+accessToken+'&callback=?'+per_page; //url
```

I want to add a view more button that if clicked will do three things;

the button `<a id="readmore" class="btn btn-success white"> View More</a>`

1. Change the text of the button from view more to view less
2. Change the `var limit = 10` to `20`
   3.Be able to revert --> `view less`

Comment: What is the purpose of `+''` in `var per_page = '&per_page='+limit+'';`?

Comment: So what are you waiting for? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, using modern web API.

```js
readmore.addEventListener('click', readmoreless);
var limit = 10;
function readmoreless(){
  if(limit == 10){
    readmore.innerHTML = "View Less";
    limit = 20;
  } else {
    readmore.innerHTML = "View More";
    limit = 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="readmore" class="btn btn-success white">View More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick function to the html:

```
<a id="readmore" class="btn btn-success white" onclick="buttonClick(this)"> View More</a>
```

And create the following function in the JS:

```
function buttonClick(but) {
    if(limit==10) {
        limit = 20;
        but.innerHTML= "View less";
    } else {
        limit = 10;
        but.innerHTML = "View more";
    }
}
```

There's still the display of the content to manage, but you didn't give much information about what you want and how the data is given!

Comment: i'm pretty comfident that .HTML is a jquery function and doesn't actuallly do anything in native javascript